# how to give multiple select options for a dropdown created in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a javascript function where rows are added dynamically.

[image]

```
<script language="javascript">
   // Add row to the HTML table


                    function addRow() {    
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
                        var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            

                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //create a new cell           
                        var element1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                        element1.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                        element1.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox'); //set the id attribute   
                        element1.setAttribute('checked',true); //set checkbox by default checked  
                        cell1.appendChild(element1); //append element to cell

                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);            
                        var element2 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element2.type = "text"; 
                        element2.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element2.setAttribute('name', 'sl'+rowCount);
                        element2.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell2.appendChild(element2);      

                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);            
                        var element3 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element3.type = "textarea"; 
                        element3.setAttribute('rows', '4');
                        element3.setAttribute('cols','40');
                        element3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element3.setAttribute('name', 'discription'+rowCount);
                        cell3.appendChild(element3);         

                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);            
                        var element4 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element4.type = "text"; 
                        element4.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element4.setAttribute('name', 'quantity'+rowCount);
                        cell4.appendChild(element4);


                        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);            
                        var element5 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element5.type = "text"; 
                        element5.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element5.setAttribute('name', 'price'+rowCount);
                        cell5.appendChild(element5);



                        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);            
                        var element6 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element6.type = "text"; 
                        element6.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element6.setAttribute('name', 'CST'+rowCount);
                        element6.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell6.appendChild(element6);


                        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
                        var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
                        var optarr =  ['vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6'];
                        for(var i = 0;i<optarr.length;i++)
                        { 
                         var opt = document.createElement("option");
                         opt.text = optarr[i];
                         opt.value = optarr[i];
                         opt.className = optarr[i];
                         element7.appendChild(opt);
                       } 

                       element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
                       element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
                       element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');
                       cell7.appendChild(element7);
}
```

In the last "cell7" i have drop-down along with options,i am selecting only one option.But i need multiple options to be selected. For example: vat1 and vat3 once,vat3 and vat5 and vat2 once like these.I tried `element7.setAttribute("multiple","")`.But it is turning into a list in which i dont needed it.So i tried "jquery Multiselect" but it is out of reach for me because i really dont know about jquery and ajax that much.Any help in this one will be really appreciated.

**Edit:After using `"setAttribute('multiple','')`**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what should go wrong. I copied your example and added the call to set the multiple attribute and it seems to work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6yAVtHyVwAWBFd3TBTc7?p=preview

```
var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
element7.setAttribute('multiple', '');
var optarr =  ['vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6'];
for(var i = 0;i<optarr.length;i++)
{ 
 var opt = document.createElement("option");
 opt.text = optarr[i];
 opt.value = optarr[i];
 opt.className = optarr[i];
 element7.appendChild(opt);
} 

var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(element7);
```

Perhaps check if you made a typo in your own code, that somehow didn't make it to the example posted here.

EDIT: You feel that the default HTML representation of a multiple select is ugly. I can't say i don't agree. That said, this is standart HTML and the representation do change when you see it on a PC, Mac, iPad, Android Phone, etc.

Sounds like you would get the best visual "upgrade" by using a css framework. There are many of them out there. I can name two of the most popular ones:

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and 
[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Comment: As you can see the edited and used 'multiple setattribute'.How ugly it looks.Can we make like "vat1" is visible and on clicking then a dropdown should and i will select another one such as "vat2" or "vat3" along with "vat1"

Comment: Is there any way like i will create select and multiple option tags in html form tag but the display of the tags(created) should be done in javascript function??.I know that i am asking a weird question but if there is any way of creating then tell me please

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz Sounds like you want to do a lot in javascript. I suggest you also embrace an javascript framework like jQuery, Angular og even (my favorite) Angular2. The HTML framework Bootstrap will use jQuery in combination with css etc to create fancy dropdown's that you are looking for.